# Abrir imagem com minha Aplicação

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em java para abrir arquivos de imagem com a classe **File()**, gostaria como tornar minha aplicação a padrão para a abertura das imagens em meu computador, não sei como receber por parâmetro o caminho do arquivo para a minha aplicação.

Poderiam me ajudar, Grato.

Comment: poderia detalhar melhor o cenário e/ou adicionar partes do código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, comecemos com o código de um visualizador:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Visualizador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escolha um arquivo para abrir.", "Visualizador", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        if (args.length != 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível entender a linha de comando.", "Visualizador", JOptionPane.ERROR);
            return;
        }
        BufferedImage img;
        try {
            img = lerImagem(args[0]);
            if (img == null) throw new IOException();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível encontrar o arquivo " + args[0] + ".", "Visualizador", JOptionPane.ERROR);
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível ler o arquivo " + args[0] + ".", "Visualizador", JOptionPane.ERROR);
            return;
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JLabel jl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
            JFrame jf = new JFrame(args[0]);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            jf.add(jl);
            jf.pack();
            jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jf.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static BufferedImage lerImagem(String s) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        return lerImagem(new File(s));
    }

    private static BufferedImage lerImagem(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (!f.exists()) throw new FileNotFoundException();
        return ImageIO.read(f);
    }
}
```

Observe que o nome do arquivo é lido da linha de comando.

Compile com isso:

```
javac -encoding UTF8 Visualizador.java
```

Execute assim:

```
java Visualizador teste.png
```

Onde `teste.png` é a sua imagem. Se a imagem existir e for bem formada, ela irá carregar. Se não for, uma mensagem de erro bonitinha e amigável aparece.

Os programas que o windows associa a tipos de arquivos são `.exe`, `.com`, `.bat`, `.pif` e `.cmd`. Como isso não inclui `.jar` ou `.class`, crie esse arquivo `visualizador.bat`:

```
java Visualizador %1
```

De forma que você pode executá-lo assim:

```
visualizador teste.png
```

Agora, vamos associar o aquivo. Primeiro, acesse o tipo de arquivo que você quer e vá no menu de propriedades:

[image: PNG]

E então, clique no botão para mudar o programa padrão:

[image: Tela de propriedades]

E procure o seu aplicativo (no caso acima o `visualizador.bat`) na lista ou clique no botão para encontrá-lo em outro lugar no seu PC:

[image: Lista]

[image: Arquivo]

Com isso, ao clicar duas vezes na imagem, o seu programa abre.

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Victor, sua resposta foi exatamente o que estava procurando.